# SQLite update is not working

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

i have app contains database ,i created many tables and insert data wihtout any problem but when i update data ,the data is not updated without any problem appear in log

the code : in the class DB extends SqliteOpenHelper i have onCreate as the following code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
db.execSQL("create table table1(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, title TEXT ,detail TEXT ,source TEXT ,isFav INTEGER)");
    db.execSQL("create table table2(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, title TEXT ,detail TEXT,source TEXT ,isFav INTEGER)");
    db.execSQL("create table table3(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, title TEXT ,detail TEXT,source TEXT, isFav INTEGER)");
    db.execSQL("create table fav (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, title TEXT ,detail TEXT,source TEXT ,isFav INTEGER)");

}
```

also , this update method code :

```
 public int updateData(String tableName,Long id, int fav) {
  SQLiteDatabase  database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put("isFav",fav);

    String myid= String.valueOf(id);

    Log.w("myApp", myid+ " fav = "+fav );
    int i = database.update(tableName, contentValues, "ID=?", new String[]{myid});
    if (i > 0)
        return 1;
    else return 0;

}
```

i have another class which is listAdapter extends ArrayAdapter i want to update from this class .
getView Contains onClickListener when click on button it should be update 
:

```
 int a=db.updateData(sh.getString("listType","table1"),arrayList.get(position).getId(),1);
```

i made sure of table name (sh.getString("listType","table1")) it delivered withot problem ..
what the problem in above code .. please help me

Comment: Did you make sure you are passing the correct id using the method `getId()`? Also I think sqlite is case insensitive but just replace "ID" with "id" just to test.

Comment: yes i made sure of getId()

Comment: are you 100% sure it is the CORRECT id? I'd suggest doing  `Cursor csr = database.query(tableName,null,"where ID=?",new String[]{myid},null,null,null,null);` followed by something like `if (csr.getCount() < 1) { Log.d("DBUPDATE","Cannot update  id = " + Integer.toString(fav) + " does not exist.");}`

Comment: i made sure by your way but it seem id is correct (no error), also i made sure of all by Log.w("table name : ", tableName+ " id  = "+id+" fav = "+fav );
all values are correct as i expect , shown in log 10-18 22:55:26.398 17682-17682/haythamayyash.nasaeh W/table name :: didYouKnow id  = 6 fav = 1

Answer (score 0):

May be your id should be passed as integer not as string.
Or you can try this

```
int i = database.update(tableName, contentValues, "ID='?'", new String[]{myid});
```